# Train perceptron model using LMS for double-Moon data python

Tags: python, perceptron

I'm trying to create a on-line version (not batch) perceptron model using LMS (Least Mean Squared) algorithm. LMS known as Adaline too (i guess). I'm using double - moon dataset which includes -1 (not 0) and +1 classes for training:

[image: Double Moon seems like that:]

I implemented python code of LMS from Haykin's book:

[image: LMS description from Haykin's Neural Networks and Learning Machines book :]

And my python code is below

```
# add 1 for bias
xtrain = np.column_stack(([float(1) for i in x],x))
weights = np.array([0.0 for k in range(len(np.transpose(xtrain)))])
#learning rate
lr = 0.01
epoch=100
def getlineer(weights,xi):
    y = dot(np.transpose(xi),weights)
    #y = np.sign(y)
    return y

for i in range(epoch):
    for k in range(len(xtrain)):
        y = getlineer(weights,xtrain[k])
        e = desired[k]-y;
        weights = weights + lr  * dot(xtrain[k],e)
        print(weights)
```

But when I train the algorithm, the model couldn't learn 100% and error/weights became too high:

[image]

Moreover, i got nan values after second epoch. 
How i can get optimum weights ?  And is my code wrong or is it about dataset ?

I know there is a optimum weight which can seperate 100% accuracy.
For example, i add some code finding accuracy of each weight update:

```
def getLMS(weights):
    e=0
    for i in range(100):
        for k in range(len(xtrain)):
            y = getlineer(weights,xtrain[k])
            e = desired[k]-y;
            weights = weights + lr  * dot(xtrain[k],e)
            xx = dot(xtrain,weights);
            tt= [np.sign(k) for k in xx]
            lens = len([i for i, j in zip(desired, tt) if i == j]) 
            if lens ==len(xtrain):
                print(lens,k,i,weights)
                return weights
```

And i got during 19. iteration i got 100% seperator weigts.

Thanks very much.

Comment: try recreating this using an extant package.  It seems like your weight update ends up increasing error- possibly a flipped negative?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: First, isolate the problem as @MohammadAthar suggested: try an established LMS implementation on your data set.  I expect it will turn out to be your code: as you noted, the data set is quite separable.  Next, run some known or trivial data through your code and check the intermediate results.  This should find any first-order errors (e.g. a flipped sign).